# How to match some words from file and list all the rows of that matching word? (without regex)

Tags: ubuntu, awk, scripting, grep

Display the Employee details of all those working in a location which ends with `ore` in its location name

```
EmpID:Name:Designation:UnitName:Location:DateofJoining:Salary
1001:Thomson:SE:IVS:Mumbai:10-Feb-1999:60000
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1003:Jackson:DM:IMS:Hyderabad:23-Apr-1985:90000
1004:BobGL::ETA:Mumbai:05-Jan-2004:55000
1005:Alice:PA:::26-Aug-2014:25000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
1007:Kirsten:PM:IMS:Mumbai:26-Aug-2014:45000
1004:BobGL::ETA:Mumbai:05-Jan-2021:55000
```

Expected output:

```
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
```

Here's the code I tried, it's only showing the location but I want full details

```
cut -d ":" -f4 employee.txt | grep 'ore\>'
```

**EDIT: SOLVED**

```
grep "`cut -d ":" -f5 employee.txt | grep 'ore\>'`$" employee.txt
```

got output:

```
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
```

Thanks everyone for help :)

Comment: What is the reason for not using regex?

Comment: awk with a regexp really is the way to go here... `awk -F: '$5 ~ /ore$/' input.txt`

Comment: cut -d ":" -f4 employee.txt | grep 'ore\>'


heres the code it's only showing the location I want full details @anubhava

Comment: @Shawn I'm new to this and for exam I must use grep so can't use awk.

Comment: @Darkman can you help me with regex related to this question?
never used regex properly :"(

Comment: OP specified **(without regex)** please don't remove it otherwise answers will look irrelevant.

Answer (score 5):

Here a **non-regex approach** using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F: -v s="ore" '(n=index($5,s)) && (n + length(s)-1) == length($5)' file

1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
```

**Details:**

- `index($5,s)` function finds position of input string `ore` in fifth column i.e `$5` of each line
- `(index($5,s) + length(s)-1) == length($5)` check is to ensure that `ore` is the ending substring of `$5`

A regex approach would be simpler:

```sh
awk -F: -v s="ore" '$5 ~ s "$"' file
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation.
Can we use same with grep? or is it only for awk? 
p.s. never used awk.

Comment: Learn `awk`, it is more powerful and feature rich. btw `grep` cannot do it without regex

Comment: I start to appreciate awk more an more

Comment: @Babbaranish don't use grep for anything involving matching on fields, awk is simpler, more robust and more easily extensible. If your string was, say `.txt` instead of `ore` you could use the awk solution as-is but you couldn't just use the same `grep` solution as you did for `ore`  because now you have a regexp metachar (`.`) to have to add code to handle in the search string. Similarly if your input only had 5 fields instead of 7 you could again just use the awk solution as-is but you'd have to change any currently posted grep solution because your target string no longer has `:` after it.

Answer (score 5):

We could go with this simple `awk` solution here. Without regex approach as per OP's requirement. Simple explanation would be: check if 5th field last 3 characters are ore then print that line.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} substr($5,length($5)-2)=="ore"' Input_file
```

***Generic answer:*** As per Ed sir's nice suggestion adding here more generic solution. Where one could set value of tail as per string needs to be looked upon.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"; tail="ore"} substr($5,length($5)-length(tail)+1)==tail' Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Just in case you would change your mind to use regex.

Using awk:

```
$ awk -F: -v ends="ore" '$5~".*"ends' file.txt
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
```

Using grep:

```
$ grep 'ore:' file.txt
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
```

Or this:

```
$ grep -E '(.*:){4}.*ore:' file.txt
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
```

Answer (score 4):

Using just `grep` (With a regular expression; the only way you can avoid them in `grep` is using `grep -F`, which does literal string matching):

```sh
$ grep -E '^([^:]*:){4}[^:]*ore:' input.txt
1002:Johnson:TE::Bangalore:18-Jun-2000:50000
1006:LilySE:IVS::Bangalore:17-Dec-2015:40000
```

Explanation:

Using Extended instead of Basic Regular Expression syntax for readability:

Starting at the beginning of the line, matches four fields (0 or more non-`:` characters followed by a `:`), and then a fifth field that ends in ore (Again, 0 or more non-`:` characters, then `o`, `r`, `e`, and finally the `:` at the end of the field).

Comment: BRE version for comparison: `grep '^\([^:]*:\)\{4\}[^:]*ore:' input.txt`

Answer (score 0):

`fgrep "ore:" employee.txt`

f(ast)grep is exact string match no regex  (same as `grep -F`)

It would not know anything about which column it was matching,
so that filter would have to happen before or after.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F: '{if (substr($5,1)~"ore")print $0}' emp.txt
```

This works for exact col match

```
grep -Ri "ore" emp.txt
```

This works for whole doc match